# Quantitatively, how deep are the stable equilibrium points in GEO? How much delta-v needed to move from one to the other?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-maneuver, geostationary, hohmann-transfer

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/33171/12102) discusses a spacecraft in GEO using a two-impulse (circular → elliptical → circular) *raise & lower* maneuver to move (phase) itself by 180 degrees in longitude then return to synchrony. ([synchronicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronicity_(The_Police_album))?) over a period of weeks or months.

Since the [Geopotential is lumpy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geopotential) and the tesseral part is dominated by the quadrupole J₂₂ term, there are two maxima and two minima in the gravitational potential along a circular path around the Earth's equator.

This results in two stable equilibrium points (valleys) and two *unstable* equilibrium points (hills) that would tend to "attract" and "repel" bodies at GEO altitudes, making East-West station-keeping something that depends on longitude.

The answer estimates that the amount of delta-v necessary to get up out of one of these stable equilibrium points (and presumable also to drop down into one) to be small, and cites another estimate (of about 2 m/s per year) of the penalty to East-West station keeping at unstable points as evidence of this.

**Question:** But I'm curious about how deep these stable points are in terms of delta-v quantitatively. For a slow transfer from one stable point to the other, how much delta-v is needed to pick ones self up out of one "gravity well" and then to settle back down in the other? Can a quantitative, verifiable source be found for this, or simply calculated approximately using Earth's J₂₂?

Let's assume the initial state is zero inclination and station-keeping as been done recently so that the East-West drift has been zeroed.

Comment: You've shown some detailed orbital simulation work in the past IIRC; do you have a decent geopotential model you could just slap this problem into and see if it works?

Comment: @RussellBorogove all I know how to do is the way I apply J₂ [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/22170/12102) and [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23409/12102). I could probably add a J₂₂ term with a cos(longitude) using [this stuff](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22976/12102) but I wouldn't be confident I was doing it right without a check by someone else's calculation. So far I am [baffled how to implement gravity models into my scripts](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27779/12102) correctly. fyi I've edited the question, is that better?

Comment: Yeah, no issues now.